# Does the following infinite sum divergent?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

We have

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\sqrt{k+2} - 2 \sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k} \right)$$

I wanna check convergence or divergence. I think it diverges. First of all I write

$$ \sqrt{k+2} - 2 \sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k} = \sqrt{k+2} - \sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k} - \sqrt{k+1} = \frac{ 1}{\sqrt{k+2}+\sqrt{k+1} } - \frac{1}{ \sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1}} $$

I think the above expressions diverges by comparing with $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ using limit comparison test. Is there another way to see the fractions above diverge?

Comment: Hint: Think telescoping.

Comment: But remember to check that the terms tend to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S_N=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(\sqrt{k+2}-2\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}\right)=\sum_{k=3}^{N+2}\sqrt{k}-2\sum_{k=2}^{N+1}\sqrt{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sqrt{k} $$
hence:
$$ S_N = \sqrt{N+2}-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{N+1}+\sqrt{1} = (1-\sqrt{2})+\frac{1}{\sqrt{N+1}+\sqrt{N+2}}.$$
Since we are able to compute the partial sums and $S_N = (1-\sqrt{2})+O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\right)$, it is trivial that:

> $$ \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(\sqrt{k+2}-2\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}\right)=\color{red}{1-\sqrt{2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Use *Taylor's expansion* at order $2$: $\;\sqrt{1+u}=1+\frac12u-\frac18u^2+o(u^2)$, whence
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{k+2} - 2 \sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k}&=\sqrt k\biggl(\sqrt{1+\dfrac2k}-2\sqrt{1+\dfrac1k}+1\biggr)\\
&=\sqrt k\biggl(1+\dfrac1k-\frac1{2k^2}-2-\dfrac1k +\frac1{4k^2}+o\Bigl(\frac1{k^2}\Bigr)+1\biggr)\\
&=-\frac1{4k^{3/2}}+o\Bigl(\frac1{k^{3/2}}\Bigr)\sim_\infty-\frac1{4k^{3/2}}
\end{align*}
hence it converges by equivalence to a convergent series.